# Endless scroll using ListView in view pager in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I am using a viewpager as a parent view and inside this I am using a `ListView` and now I want to endless scroll in `ListView`.

I have to show multiple list which will be scroll in horizontal using view pager and each list  will have multiple records with endless scrolling.

So, My question is that can I load next data in `ListView` without reload the viewpager?

Comment: The ListView is independent of the viewpager, and have nothing to do with each other.  What you are asking is related to the listview - and I am not sure you can do what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your ListView endless
Try this [EndlessListView](https://github.com/JafarKhQ/EndlessListView) that i wrote, there is an example too.